# C string memory allocation implicit?

Tags: c, string, multidimensional-array, memory-management, arrays

The `sizeof(test)` returns 24.  It is an array of 3 `char*` pointers which are 8 bytes each on my machine.  My question is does C properly allocate space for the characters as well?  I guess it does because this works but I want to make sure I am doing it correctly.

```
char* test[] = {"QW", "BT", "GH"};
int size = sizeof(test) / sizeof(char*);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it does. The characters may be in a read-only portion of the memory though.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the compiler will allocate space (generally in the read-only static data section) for the string literals.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The value is located in memory at the address pointed by the *char pointer used in the array. So yes, it is stored in the memory.

Answer (score 0):

My rewording of 6.4.5/5 in [the Standard](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)

> ... string literals are implemented as arrays of **static storage** duration with 'char' type ...

So, the objects are allocated as any other `static` variable

```
static int arr[100] = {0};
if (strcmp(foo, "bar")) exit(0);
int *ptr = malloc(100 * sizeof *ptr);
```

The array `arr` and the string literal `"bar"` are allocated in the same way; different than the way `ptr` is allocated.

Comment: Note that they're also non-modifiable.